# How to change the filtering pattern of the Webix dateFilter?

Tags: javascript, html, date, filtering, webix

How to specify the format of the dateFilter in Webix datatable?

I have a grid where dates are formatted to `"%d.%m.%Y"`:

```
columns:[
  { id:"date", header:[{ content:"dateFilter" }], width:160, format:myFormat }
]
```

where `myFormat` is `webix.Date.dateToStr("%d.%m.%Y");` The result is dd.mm.yyyy

Here's a snippet with the similar grid: http://webix.com/snippet/1ec86aa8

The point is that the dateFilter still requires the full dates as `%m-%d-%Y` (mm-dd-yyyy)

[image: pattern of the Webix date filter]

So I'm looking for a way to change this predefined pattern. Any suggestion are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dateFilter convert user entered date from str to date using [webix.i18n.dateFormatDate](http://docs.webix.com/api__i18n_dateformatdate.html)

By the way, it does more thing. For exemple you can enter "<1996" and so it will not convert using the above method date but extract the year.

Then it convert the guessed date to an interger and perform an interger comparison with data's dates

Sadly "webix.i18n.dateFormatDate" use the webix.i18n.dateFormat which depend the locale to convert string to date. and there is no way to customize the format used by dateFilter.

A solution for you is to create a custom filter which do the same job as dateFilter but using your own date convertion :

Here is a modified webix code of dateFilter :

```
webix.ui.datafilter.myDateFilter = webix.extend({
    format:function(value){
        if (value === "") return "";
        var date = new Date();

        if (value.indexOf("today") != -1){
            date = webix.Date.dayStart(date);
        } else if (value.indexOf("now") == -1){
            var parts = value.match(/[0-9]+/g);
            if (!parts||!parts.length) return "";
            if (parts.length < 3){
                parts.reverse();
                date = new Date(parts[0], (parts[1]||1)-1, 1);
            } else
                // Change here
                date = webix.Date.strToDate("%d.%m.%Y")(value.replace(/^[>< =]+/,""));

        }

        return date.valueOf();
    }
}, webix.ui.datafilter.numberFilter);
```

Updated snippet : http://webix.com/snippet/20c0175a

Comment: Thanks for such a great explanation, I didn't know that. But what if just redefine the `dateFormat` as provided [here](http://docs.webix.com/api__i18n_dateformat_other.html)? Will it affect  something critically? AFAICS, it also works well [(sample)](http://webix.com/snippet/50df9306)

Comment: Yes, you can freely redefine date formats in your i18n file (that's what it's there for). Nothing critical depend on it (but most of things needed when convert date to string and string to date against the locale)